# User permission fetching from database - concept problem

Tags: mysql, database-design, asp-classic, roles

I have a table users

```
ID    status
1     5
2     50
3     60
4     999
5     5
```

Each user in table has it's status. Status means like:

```
5 = normal user
50 = article writer
60 = blog writer
999 = administrator
```

Until I had normal linear system of ascending status values everything was Ok. If page was accessible only for admins I did a session check for status 999, if the page was accessible by minimal status user I did a check if status > 2 etc... It works without accessing the database (I have statuses fetched in session variables so the mysql is queried only when session is timed out and on first visit).

Now I have a problem with article writers and blog administrators... There is a concept problem. I can only apply the = or > to statuses, so allow only one of the statuses or any status that is higher. Admin can see everything so it has highest number.

Now I want that user 2 would also be able to be a blog writer, so in fact to have 2 exact roles. He needs to have status 50 and 60 at the same time. And 60 is not HIGHER because I don't want every blog writer to be able to see article administration also. What to do now?

I can of course put in status columns 50,60 and then parse the right one out, but I would loose the number column and I think this is bad practice to misuse the column field for more than one value.

Logical way would be to make a status table like

```
IDuser     status
2          50
2          60
3          60
1          5
5          5
4          999
```

So when I am on a blog page I can query the exact needed status and one user could have more than one role...

BUT... As I wrote, I have status in session variable using classic ASP not to query the database on every page. If I make another status table I will need to query status table on every page to see if the role for that user is included. I'd like to have this info in memory somehow, but I am not sure how.

Or maybe there is some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a hashmap solution that keeps db tables and code readable can be:

on header.inc

```
'add new tasks  here  (and in perfiles table) '
mask_order = "write_article,read_article,write_blog,read_blog"

' this function can be coded 2 ways: checking bad parameters or   '
' not checking bad parameters (best perfomance, but unpredictible problems on wrong calls), i coded this way here '
function can_user(what)
    x = split(" " & mask_order, what)    ' the extra space is needed here '
    x = ubound(split(x(0), ","))+1
    can_user = (session("mask") and 2^x)<>0
end function
```

on login.asp  or session restart

```
sql="select users.usuario, perfiles.* from users inner join perfiles on users.perfil=perfiles.perfil" _
 & " where usuario = '" & limpia(quien) & "' and pass ' = '" & limpia(password) & "';"
r.open sql, c
ok = not r.eof
if ok then 
    mask = 0: i = 0
    for each campo in split(mask_order, ",")
      i = i +1
      if r(campo) then mask = mask or 2^i
    next
    session("mask") = mask
```

on each file required

```
if can_user("read_article") then ....
```

Comment: with this aproach, be careful that action_name constatns are not substrings of others.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hashmap of the various 'status' values and OR your user with whatever permission they are asking for.

Comment: One of my ideas was to use bits to check for permissions. Using 256 values I could have 8 permissions, one bit for each... Could you write a little more what did you mean to use hashmap? Is this something similar to using bits?

Comment: Same idea. Makes it easy to combine permission types into one column like you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can still store multiple statuses in a session variable, I would recommend a comma delimited list:

```
Session.Contents("Status") = "50,60"
```

You can then get the list as an Array ie

```
Dim Status
'Check if there is a comma in the list
If (InStr(Session.Contents("Status"), ",")) Then
   Status = Split(Session.Contents("Status"), ",")
Else
   Status Array(Session.Contents("Status"))
End If

'Use a for loop to check if the user has access
i = 0
For i = LBound(Status) To UBound(Status)
   'Do your check here
Next
```

Comment: Thanx. This would work, yes. But is it fast enough to do this on every page?

Comment: Its going to be faster in most cases then calling the database everytime and you are doing simple string manipulation.

Comment: Isn't it against the DB concept to store more than 1 bit of info in a single cell?

Comment: You would store the rights separately in the DB, like the status table you provided and only use one session variable to store all the rights for the user.  ASP Classic's HashMap is the ASP Dictionary object, but you do not want to store objects in the Session scope as the objects are not thread safe.

Comment: Aha I see! So I get the permissions from separate table and put them in session delimited with comma. On every page I split the sesssion variable? I do not understand what you mean by thread safe?

Comment: More information on Sessions and threading http://learnasp.com/freebook/asp/sessionoverview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I do with two tables:
"users" has "profiles" asociated and
"profiles" has "alowed actions" asociated
you can mantain your "*normal linear system of ascending status*" based on "status" and you can start migrating to this new model 
here is a simplficated part of my login.aps (clasic) I also maintain "alowed actions" on session
perhaps (I'm not shure, if it is good as a long term solution) you can use "status" field as the join betwin users and alowed_actions_by_profile tables

```
sql="select users.usuario, perfiles.* from users inner join perfiles on users.perfil=perfiles.perfil" _
 & " where usuario = '" & limpia(quien) & "' and pass ' = '" & limpia(password) & "';"
r.open sql, c
ok = not r.eof
if ok then 
    for each campo in r.fields
      if campo.name<>"usuario" then session("can_" & campo.name) = r(campo.name)
    next
    session("user") = r("usuario")
```

here profile table is like

```
perfil         varchar(20) not null,   
write_article  bolean null,   
read_article   bolean not null,
write_blog     bolean null,   
read_blog      bolean not null,
and so on
```

and you check in your code as

```
if session("can_write_blog") then ....
```

Comment: This would work, but I think I need for every user to have like 8 session variables, for each permission one. This would be fast but I am not sure how is it memory wise to have 8 session variables for each of 40.000 users... I now have about 10 sessions variables for each user and thr 8 GB system manages it ok. But another 8 just for permissions...?